# Rails 7: Turbo stream is showing partial only

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am having a problem with the turbo-rails gem. First I installed the latest version in my Rails 7 application. On my site, I have a select input which is wrapped in a form, with a partial below that form that shows the data. Now I want to apply a filter using the select and dynamically update the data using this turbo-rails package. My form html looks like this:

```
<div class="users">
    <div class="filters">
        <%= form_with url: '/users/load', method: :get, data: { turbo_frame: :form_response } do |form| %>
            <%= render partial: "shared/select", locals: {
                placeholder: 'Gender', 
                width: '90px', 
                options: @genders,
                classes: 'filter',
                name: 'gender',
            } %>
            <%= form.submit %>
        <% end %>
    </div>

    <%= turbo_frame_tag :form_response do %>
        <%= render partial: "users/user_list", locals: {
            users: @users
        } %>
    <% end %>
</div>
```

In my routes, I created this get request which is forwared to a `load` method in my controller like this:

```
get '/users' => "users#index"
get '/users/load' => "users#load"
```

And then in my controller I have the 2 methods written like this:

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController

    before_action :require_user

    USERS_PER_PAGE = 15

    def index
        @genders = ["Male", "Female"]
        @users = User
                            .limit(USERS_PER_PAGE)
                            .order(:creation_date).reverse_order
    end

    def load
        @users = User
                            .limit(USERS_PER_PAGE)
                            .order(:creation_date).reverse_order
                            
        if params[:gender]
            @users = @users.where(gender: params[:gender])
        end

        respond_to do |format|
            format.html { render partial: 'users/user_list', locals: { users: @users } }
        end
    end
end
```

The problem is that when I go to this page, select a gender and hit the submit button, I get to see the user data with the correct genders, but I only see the partial loaded, so the rest of the page is gone. I can see in the network tab of developer tools in Chrome that the request headers is set to:

```
text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/avif,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8,application/signed-exchange;v=b3;q=0.9
```

I want to use the turbo-streams instead of the turbo frames, because I need to update more of these items on the same page. Why is it not rendering the content inside the page, instead of rendering the partial only?

How can this be fixed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To answer your question, you're rendering a partial without turbo stream or turbo frame, so you're only getting a partial as response.

I think, a few examples will explain everything.

```rb
# config/routes.rb
resources :users
```

```rb
# app/controllers/users_controller.rb
def index
  scope = User.order(created_at: :desc)
  scope = scope.where(name: params[:search]) if params[:search]
  @users = scope
end
```

---

"Preserve log" is quite useful when working with turbo frame and it redirects and clears the console:
*https://developer.chrome.com/docs/devtools/console/reference/#persist*

---

#### Turbo *FRAME* using *GET* request with *HTML* response

We are in `index` action and the form is submitting back to `index`.

```rb
# app/views/users/index.html.erb

# expect :users_index turbo frame in a response      vvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvv
<%= form_with url: users_path, method: :get, data: { turbo_frame: :users_index } do |f| %>
  <%= f.text_field :search %>
  <%= f.submit %>
<% end %>

# turbo frame in a response needs to match turbo frame on the current page,
# since we're rendering the same page again, we have the matching frame,
# only content inside this frame is updated.
<%= turbo_frame_tag :users_index do %>
  <%= render @users %>
<% end %>

# If you render some other page, you have to wrap it in
# `turbo_frame_tag :users_index`
```

If you want to update the url as well, so you don't lose the search on refresh:

```rb
<%= turbo_frame_tag :users_index, data: { turbo_action: :advance } do %>
  <%= render @users %>
<% end %>
```

---

#### Turbo *STREAM* using *GET* request with *TURBO_STREAM* response

You have to set `data-turbo-stream="true"` to send a *GET* stream.

```rb
# app/views/users/index.html.erb

<%= form_with url: users_path, method: :get, data: { turbo_stream: true } do |f| %>
  <%= f.text_field :search %>
  <%= f.submit %>
<% end %>

<%= tag.div id: :users_index do %>
  <%= render @users %>
<% end %>
```

Add `turbo_stream` format to respond to this request:

```rb
# app/views/users/index.turbo_stream.erb

# update content inside <div id="users_index">
<%= turbo_stream.update :users_index do %>
  <%= render @users %>
<% end %>

# add another `turbo_stream` here if you'd like.
```

---

#### Turbo *STREAM* using *POST* request with *TURBO_STREAM* response

```rb
# config/routes.rb

resources :users do
  # # add `search` action
  # post :search, on: :collection

  # i'll be lazy and post to :index
  post :search, action: :index, on: :collection
end
```

*POST* form submissions are sent as *TURBO_STREAM* by default and it will render `index.turbo_stream.erb`.

```rb
# app/views/users/index.html.erb

<%= form_with url: search_users_path do |f| %>
  <%= f.text_field :search %>
  <%= f.submit %>
<% end %>

<%= tag.div id: :users_index do %>
  <%= render @users %>
<% end %>
```

```rb
# app/views/users/index.turbo_stream.erb

<%= turbo_stream.update :users_index do %>
  <%= render @users %>
<% end %>
```

---

#### Test set up

Just do a simple set up:

```bash
rails --version
# Rails 7.0.4

rails new turbo-test -j esbuild
cd turbo-test
bin/rails g scaffold User name
bin/rails db:migrate
open http://localhost:3000/users
bin/dev
```

```rb
# app/controllers/users_controller.rb

def create
  @user = User.new(user_params)

  respond_to do |format|
    if @user.save
      # Add this line:
      format.turbo_stream { render turbo_stream: turbo_stream.prepend(:users, partial: "user", locals: { user: @user }) }

      format.html { redirect_to user_url(@user), notice: "User was successfully created." }
    else
      format.html { render :new, status: :unprocessable_entity }
    end
  end
end
```

```rb
# app/views/users/index.html.erb

# submit form
<%= render "form", user: User.new %>

# new user gets prepended here
<div id="users">
  <%= render @users %>
</div>
```

Comment: Using the Turbo STREAM GET request, I am still getting full page refreshes when hitting submit in the form. I have the content you said for the `# app/controllers/users_controller.rb`. I thought I needed to use something like `format.turbo_stream`?

Comment: In the logs with preserve logs, I only see this line when I hit the submit button:
`Navigated to http://localhost:3000/users?gender=Male&commit=Save+`

Comment: I did upgrade from rails 6 to rails 7, and I only installed this turbo-rails gem. Is there something I have to install as well?

Comment: @A.Vreeswijk just type `Turbo` in the console to check if you have it. it should render `index.turbo_stream.erb` automatically. make sure you're all the way up to date to the current version. GET streams is a recent addition. Start with POST stream or turbo frame, make sure that works as expected. it works with the `index` action I showed, `index.html.erb` and `index.turbo_stream.erb`.

Comment: I did a clean Rails 7 install with just a simple page with turbo_stream and the POST request, but it is STILL refreshing the entire page. I tried running `Turbo` in my application terminal, but that gives me: `sh: turbo: not found`. Any ideas? I'm lost....

Comment: I meant browser console, checking for javascript. See update ^ with a fresh test set up.

Comment: Yes, I finally got it working. I think I had to add: `import { Turbo } from "@hotwired/turbo-rails"` and `Turbo.session.drive = true` to my `app.ts`. Thank you for your help!

Comment: is there a way to store the parameters in the URL for turbo_streams with GET requests. I have tried adding `data: { turbo_action: :advance }` to the `div` of my turbo_stream content, but that doesn't work. Let me know if you can!

Comment: @A.Vreeswijk that only works with turbo frame.